# Conditional WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need a solution for a conditional `WHERE` clause in SQL Server. I can't figure out how to add the functions to the `WHERE` clause depending on the declared variables. I'll bracket the conditional parts with the needed logic

```
DECLARE @distance bigint
DECLARE @photosneeded bigint

SET @distance * 50

SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE
  [IF @distance > 0 THEN distance_function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)<=@distance END]
  AND
  [IF @photosneeded>0 THEN u.photo IS NOT NULL AND u.photo <>'' END]
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table#Logical_implication

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can be done using a plain WHERE clause:

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE
(@distance <= 0 or (distance_function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)<=@distance))
AND
(@photosneeded <= 0 or (u.photo IS NOT NULL AND u.photo <>''))
```

However you need to be careful with this kind of condition in the clause, because it can really screw up execution plan optimization.  See @Iain's answer for more on why.

Comment: In this particular instance, am I OK with the execution plan on SQL ?

Comment: Your mileage may vary.  I see nothing about it in the "What's New" docs for SQL Server 2012, but that doesn't mean it hasn't changed.  You should just be aware that while it will work logically, the performance may not be great, and Iain's solution will almost certainly perform better.

Answer (score 3):

My advice would be make that into three seperate procedures - one for the complete query just using the first clause, another for the complete query just using the second clause, and a third as the "master" which calls either one depending on the condition. There have been issues in the past with SQL Server only compiling the first used branch of a conditional clause (I'm not sure whether that is the case with 2008), so using seperate stored procedures protects you from that, and it's an easy way to organise things.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it is still a problem in 2008- thus the warning at the bottom of my answer.  I think your answer explains the root cause more clearly though.

Comment: That is the way to go, I found that same piece of advice in book "MCTS Self-Paced Training Kit (Exam 70-433): Microsoft® SQL Server 2008 Database Development", so it still applies to SQL Server 2008. Execution plan usage is optimized because several simple reusable execution plans are easily combined in an execution plan belonging to the "master" stored procedure.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisShain, I think you beat me to the answer by 16 seconds! :) Interesting to see how it can be done with a standard where clause.

Comment: I'm using SQL 2012 now, does this apply to 2012 as well?

Comment: Don't know about SQL Server 2012. On pages 163-164 of the above mentioned book it states that if there is a branching inside procedure and code blocks belonging to each branch are quite different, each code block should be made a procedure. Inside "master" proc those procedures would be called depending on the branching condition; CREATE PROC Proc1 BEGIN IF <condition> THEN <blockA> ELSE <blockB> END - can be replaced by CREATE PROC Proc1 BEGIN IF <condition> THEN EXEC Proc_blockA ELSE EXEC Proc_blockB END You can try both solutions and review performance metrics to see if there is difference.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM users u
WHERE
 ( @distance <= 0 or distance_function(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2)<=@distance )
 and
 ( @photosneeded <= 0 or isnull(u.photo, '') <> '' )
```